# Can not get the ASP MVC4 APIController Post Method to read JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm having problems posting my JSON data back to my api controller in my MVC 4 project.
Here's my javascript:

```
 self.saveInvestment = function () {
        var investmentdata = ko.mapping.toJSON( { "InvestmentSummary": self.InvestmentSummary } );

        $.ajax({
            url: "../api/investment/",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: investmentdata,
            success: function () {
                alert('hi');
            }
        });

    };
```

Here's my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]InvestmentSummary val)
        {
            string blah;
            if (val.InvestmentDetails[0] != null)
                blah = val.InvestmentDetails[0].Cost.ToString();

        }
```

Here's the header info from fiddler:

```
application/json; charset=UTF-8
http://localhost:1961
http://localhost:1961/Investment
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

POST http://localhost:1961/api/investment/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1961
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2470
Origin: http://localhost:1961
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:1961/Investment
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

{"InvestmentSummary":{"InvestmentDetails":[{"Cost":"11","FairValue":0,"Tranches":[{"IDTranche":null.......
```

The JSON is formatted properly and I double checked with JSON Lint.
When I debug my application, in my controller, "val" has no data in it.
What am I doing wrong??
Thanks!

Edit:
Here's my class definition of InvestmentSummary:

```
    public class InvestmentSummary : TransactionSummary
    {
        public InvestmentSummary()
        {
            this.InvestmentDetails = new List<InvestmentDetail>();
        }

        public List<InvestmentDetail> InvestmentDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

I think my problem is that my JSON is using InvestmentDetails but my class name is InvestmentDetail?  Anyone, please help?  Thanks

***Second Edit****
My full JSON has this structure:

```
var init = {
        InvestmentSummary: {
            InvestmentDetails: [],
            IDTransactionSummary:null,
            TxnParameter: {},
            TxnDate: "",
            Fund: {},
            PortfolioCompany: {}
        }
    };
```

From the help of tpeczek, I was able to read in InvestmentDetails.
But now how do I also get the rest of my JSON?
In my javascript, the JSON is built properly however, when it reaches my controller,
only the InvestmentDetails are present.  All other children of InvestmentSummary is gone!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you shouldn't be wrapping the object into one more object in your JavaScript:

```
 self.saveInvestment = function () {
        var investmentdata = ko.mapping.toJSON(self.InvestmentSummary);

        $.ajax({
            url: "../api/investment/",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: investmentdata,
            success: function () {
                alert('hi');
            }
        });

    };
```

Also you shouldn't need `FromBody` in this case:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(InvestmentSummary val)
{
    string blah;
    if (val.InvestmentDetails[0] != null)
    blah = val.InvestmentDetails[0].Cost.ToString();    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Now that I look at it, I think my problem lies in the pluralization of JSON.  My POCO object name is InvestmentDetail.  But my JSON is InvestmentDetails (Which was the name of the List of InvestmentDetail).  What would be the best way to remedy this?  Thanks

Comment: @user1175857 For JSON deserialization important part are properties names and types compatibility, not names of types. What results did you get when you tried it the why I have described?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response tpeczek.  But your solution totally worked.  THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Hi @tpeczek or anyone else.  I just noticed this solution does not include all of my JSON.  Along with InvestmentDetails, I also have TxnDate property and Fund array.  I've edit the original post.  Please help!

Comment: @user1175857 You need to create a single object which will correspond to JSON format, please POST your entire JSON (collections might contain only one element - just need to see properties) and I will try to propose an server side object for deserializing.

Comment: @user1175857 Also please post the `TransactionSummary` so we can see what properties are already covered by the base class. And in the end please tell which properties doesn't bind.